# Alpine Packages missing package cassandra-cpp-driver

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

Wonder if anyone has tried the Cassandra-cpp-driver on Alpine?
I found this package: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/cassandra-cpp-driver

But when I tried "apk add cassandra-cpp-driver", it cannot find it

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  cassandra-cpp-driver (missing):
    required by: world[cassandra-cpp-driver]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a 'testing' package, you need to install it like this

```
apk add cassandra-cpp-driver --update-cache --repository \
    http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/
```

See https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Add_a_Package

Comment: **Do NOT use --allow-untrusted!** This option skips signature verification, so it’s insecure. It’s not just stupid, but also pointless, because dl-3.alpinelinux.org is an official Alpine repository, so use has required keys in the system.